# PHP: Is it possible to save the uploading file content directly into DB without save to tmp directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I know it is possible to read file content from `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` and save the content into DB.
But I think it is a performance waste.

Is it possible to read the file content directly from the HTTP post stream?

Comment: `$_FILES` in not a superglobal, 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

that means it cannot be available on any stream

Comment: u could always take the binari data(in the client), and stream it via http body, and then write it directly into the db.

Comment: @yaron Yes, I upload the file and anther param in the format of http multi-part-form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible via  `PUT` .....  you can get the raw input ... but you would still need to parse it your self

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I think `$_FILES` is faster and better

Comment: It will work for POST actually but not for forms with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: However, the php will still write the content to a temp file, right?

Comment: @Terry are you using a web from or you are sending the image form an application

Comment: @Baba From an application.

Comment: I can use PUT. But I have anther param need to be uploaded. So that will cause additional http request. I am using Ngix+Php(fastCGI). I just want to make sure which is the best way to deal with this issue.

Comment: Add the parameter to the GET url .. it does not have to be POST or don't use HTTP because even if you use [http_put_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-put-file.php) you still need to parse ...

Comment: At last: I decide to save the files in the FileSystem instead of saving them to Mongo GridFS.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

No, PHP has an internal data structure (the $_FILES array) that stores all uploaded file info, and there is no other way of accessing that info elsewhere in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with POST request.
With PUT requests, you can use stdin.

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
```

Comment: However, the php will still write the content to a temp file, right?